How to map CapsLock to Esc and Ctrl in Autohotkey?
How to remap Capslock key in a way that pressing and releasing it registers as Escape key  but pressing and holding it registers as Ctrl key modifier?
I'm looking for a windows solution preferably using Autohotkey v2.

#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

; Remap Capslock to Ctrl:
Capslock::Ctrl  

Capslock Up::{
    Send "{Ctrl Up}"
    If (A_PriorKey = "Capslock") ; if Capslock was pressed alone
        Send "{Esc}"
}


This doesn't seem to work with repeated keypresses. e.g. press CAPSLOCK then V twice to paste twice.
